# Create a method in utility class without declaring it as static

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a math games. When a user submit a correct/incorrect answer, it shows a message. I want to extract that method and put it in a separate class so I can call it from anywhere. Is there a way to do that **without** setting the method as **static** and being able to call like any other methods in that class: `showCustomNotofication();` for example.

Comment: Without the method being `static`, no.

Comment: Why? What's the purpose of the restriction?

Comment: If i set it to static, then i keep getting errors that i must set all variables i pass to static. Some of them i just can't set to static. I changed the method and now i use `CustomNotification cm  = new CustomNotification` then i am able to use cm.showCustomNotification(); But i want, if it possible of course, to call it witout cm.*. Maybe i just didn't understand how static method works and have to try again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an enum instead, but I am not sure why you would want to as using `static` is the simplest and fastest.

```
enum Utility {
    INSTANCE;

    public void showCustomNotification() {
       // blah
    }
}
```

can be called using

```
Utility.INSTANCE.showCustomNotification();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class object where your "showCustomNotofication();" message is present say

```
NotificationManger manager=new NotificationManger ();
manager.showCustomNotofication();
```

Call it anywhere when you need them

**EDIT:-**

Static variable is used when you want the value to be present throughout the application and static method is used when you dont wish to create the intance of the class and the method belongs to the class and not the instance

Comment: *Static method is used when you want the value to be present throughout the application* not sure what you mean with your last sentence, but a `static` method is not the same as a `static` field and this sentence looks to refer to `static` fields.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry..I meant static variable